# Azure Messages appear to be stuck

Tags: azure

I am using Windows Azure Service Bus. I created a Topic and am using a subscription to which partners send messages to. What I notice is that the "Message Count" stays at 1923 and does not come down. When a new message is posted to the queue (or subs in this case), it goes up to 1924 and then my service polls the message and it will bring it back to 1923. It looks like 1923 messages appear to be stuck and unable to retrieve.

Why does this happen and how do I retrieve these messages?

Comment: Check this post as I had same issues: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25762485/azure-service-bus-queue-messages-got-stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the 1923 messages are present in the dead letter queue and those messages will not appear in the actual queue for you to retrieve
You can use "Service Bus explorer" to check the messages that are present in the queues and dead letter queues.
You can download the Service bus explorer in the following path:
http://servicebus.codeplex.com/

Happy Coding,
-Vijay.

Comment: Anyway to get rid of these messages or at least look at what they are before deleting?