# Message is stuck at azure service Bus. How to retrigger delivery of message?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

Message is stuck on azure service bus for last 24 hours. It is not getting delivered to Listener.
Active message: 2
message time to live : 14 days
Message lock duration: 5 minutes
max delivery count:1 (we have reduced it to 1 as 5 minutes is not enough to finish processing)
Is there any way we can re trigger these messages to the listener?

Answer (score 0):

In your listener, please make sure you need to recheck once the active and `deadletter` queue.

If you are using `Recieve();`/ `RecieveBatch();`/ `onMessage();` in your listener it will receive the queues messages not to get the stuck or not processed messages, for that you have to use the **Complete()** or **abandon()**.

**complete():**

Complete() is used for any message you have to process.

**abandon()**

The [abandon()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.queueclient.abandon?view=azure-dotnet) is immediately available in the queue for another worker to process. And check the [BrokeredMessage.Abandon()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.brokeredmessage.abandon?view=azure-dotnet#microsoft-servicebus-messaging-brokeredmessage-abandon(system-collections-generic-idictionary((system-string-system-object))))

**DeliveryCount**

The [DeliveryCount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.queuedescription.maxdeliverycount?view=azure-dotnet) property is used to not process a message twice.

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28010714/15997690)

> Message lock duration: 5 minutes max delivery count:1 (we have reduced it to 1 as 5 minutes is not enough to finish processing) Is there any way we can re-trigger these messages to the listener?

The **Maximum delivery count** is our flexibility only we can **Gets or sets** the maximum delivery count. A message is automatically deadlettered after this number of deliveries.

The **Lock Duration (Seconds)** has some limitations like we can **Gets or sets** the duration of a peek lock. The maximum value for LockDuration is 5 minutes(default is 1 minute).

Please refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.queuedescription?view=azure-dotnet) for more information